# Grub FlipFlop Boot

Tags: boot, windows-10, grub, opensuse

Is it possible to configure grub2 boot loader to flipflip boot between two different OS?

MY set-up is that I have a beefy lab computer that is by some people to run Window 10 and others Linux (Suse), at the moment we just have a normal dual boot. The downside this requires someone to be physically in front of the machine to pick the required OS on reboot to switch between OSs.

Can I configure the grub loader to change default boot OS/partition on each boot-up so that we can remotely switch between OS.

Virtualisation or one OS inside the other is not an option sadly, as there are driver and performance issues related to the connected hardware.

Comment: It is open source. So you have that. But any changes you make will need to be reconciled into updates.  You could also script a custom menu.lst on each boot with a rename. I understand you want to toggle on big red switch, but setting it to "last used" and using KVM over IP to reselect may also be an option. Otherwise actual restarts will need to be doubled.

Answer (score 0):

he only way to get direct remote access to Grub is to use a serial console. The only thing running on the system when Grub loads is itself. But you can use Ethernet-to-Serial(SNI) adapter and use [grub on serial](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Serial-terminal.html#Serial-terminal). For lilo you have to edit lilo.conf. I dont know exact steps for grub2 though.

You can alternately use KVM (KVM via Ethernet specifically) or if your BIOS has ability to install plugins/addons or accept commands over USB or ethernet, you can use that.

Edit: If you have PXE support on your PC, [Booting GRUB from the network | gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Network.html)